# Tapestry 5 accessing page components/properties from other components used in the page

Tags: components, tapestry

I am switching from Tapestry 3 to Tapestry 5 and I am a little bit confused about some topics.
In tapestry 3 it is possible to access page components/properties from other components used in the same page using for example:

```
<span jwcid="@RenderBlock" block="ognl:page.components.myMenu"/>
```

`myMenu` has already been defined in the html page as follows:

```
<span jwcid="myMenu@Block">  
  <span jwcid="@MyMenu"/>  
<span/>
```

`MyMenu` component is defined in its own files.

How would it be possible to do the same thing with Tapestry 5?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Tapestry 5 has special binding prefixes for this purpose:

block:foo binds the parameter to

component:bar binds the parameter to component with t:id="bar"

Beyond that, you can use @Inject to inject a Block or Component, and expose properties for those injections.

Your example might look something like:

```
<t:delegate to="block:mymenu"/>

...

<t:block id="mymenu"> ... </t:block>
```

assuming they are both defined in the same template; otherwise you have to arrange parameters or properties to tie things together.

Comment: Hello Howard. Thank you for the answer. It is almost done. I just need to check that the needed blocks already exists in the page before displaying them. With Tapestry 3 this was performed via `page.components.myMenu != null`

Comment: Check out ComponentResources, it should have the methods you need.

Comment: Hello used `resources.getPage().getComponentResources().getBlock("MyMenu");` to implement my request. Thank you very much.